# Ruby - run Thor command without argument

Tags: ruby, arguments, thor

I have to use this command to execute the script:

`$ruby file.rb keyword --format oneline --no-country-code --api-key=API`

Where, the `format`, `no-country-code`, `api-key` are `thor` options. The `keyword` is the argument in my method:

```
class TwitterTrendReader < Thor
    method_option :'api-key', :required => true
    method_option :format
    method_option :'no-country-code', :type => :boolean

    def execute (keyword)
        #read file then display the results matching `keyword`
    end

default_task :execute
end
```

The problem is the `keyword` is optional, if I run the command without the `keyword`, the script should print all entries in the file, otherwise, it only display the entries matching the `keyword`.

so I have this code:

```
if ARGV.empty?
  TwitterTrendReader.start ''
else
  TwitterTrendReader.start ARGV
end
```

It only works when I specify a `keyword` but without `keyword`, I get this:

```
$ruby s3493188_p3.rb --api-key="abC9hsk9"
ERROR: "s3493188_p3.rb execute" was called with no arguments
Usage: "s3493188_p3.rb [keyword] --format oneline --no-country-code --api-key=API-KEY"
```

So please tell me what is the proper way that I could make the argument optional. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation of `def execute (keyword)` is of arity `1` (that said, it declares one mandatory parameter.) Make the parameter optional, if you want to have an ability to omit it.

Change

```
def execute (keyword)
    #read file then display the results matching `keyword`
end
```

to:

```
def execute (keyword = nil)
  if keyword.nil?
    # NO KEYWORD PASSED
  else
    # NORMAL PROCESSING
  end
end
```